# SQL statement to combine two tables and show delta values in one row

Tags: sql

I'm trying to match 2 tables using a SQL statement where attributes form one column are combined and the other values (delta) will be shown in the same row. For example the following 2 tables are given (which already result from some filtered and counted SQL querys):

Table 1:

| Name | Count |
| --- | --- |
| First | 4 |
| Second | 7 |
| Third | 2 |
| Fourth | 12 |
| Fith | 5 |

Table 2:

| Name | Count |
| --- | --- |
| First | 13 |
| Second | 6 |
| Third | 2 |
| Fourth | 12 |
| Sixth | 3 |

Expected result:

| Name | Count table 1 | Count table 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | 4 | 13 |
| Second | 7 | 6 |
| Third | 2 | 2 |
| Fourth | 12 | 12 |
| Fith | 5 | 0 |
| Sixth | 0 | 3 |

Tried to use UNION and googled but don't get the needed result.

Comment: Look into SQL joins, https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Union will append result sets together vertically - you need to use a join.

Comment: I agree that you should look into joins. w3schools is a site I don't recommend, though. The page linked to is a good example. There is no explanation on the syntax; which keywords are mandatory, which are optional? The using clause is not mentioned. It is made belive there exist only four joins; the cross joins is not mentioned. There is not even a remark on right joins being generally avoided, for they can make queries close to unreadable. Venn diagrams are only partly helpful, because in joins we join rows and may thus duplicate some data, which the diagrams don't show...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should just be a simple join:

```
select table1.Name, table1.Count, table2.Count
from table1
     join table2 on table1.Name = table2.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an inner join statement.

```
"SELECT [Table 1].Name, [Table 1].Count, [Table 2].count FROM [Table 1] INNER JOIN [Table 2] ON [Tabel 1].Name = [Table 2].Name"
```

Answer (score 1):

You just try this one.

```
Create TABLE #A
(
    name_a varchar(50),
    column_a int  
)
Create TABLE #B
(
    name_b varchar(50),
    column_b int  
)

Insert INTO #A(name_a,column_a) values('First',4)
Insert INTO #A(name_a,column_a) values('Second',7)
Insert INTO #A(name_a,column_a) values('Third',2)
Insert INTO #A(name_a,column_a) values('Fourth',12)
Insert INTO #A(name_a,column_a) values('Fith',5)

Insert INTO #B(name_b,column_b) values('First',13)
Insert INTO #B(name_b,column_b) values('Second',6)
Insert INTO #B(name_b,column_b) values('Third',2)
Insert INTO #B(name_b,column_b) values('Fourth',12)
Insert INTO #B(name_b,column_b) values('Sixth',3)

select isnull(#A.name_a,#B.name_b) as Name, isnull(#A.column_a,0) as 'Count table 1', isnull(#B.column_b,0) as 'Count table 2'
from #A
     full outer join #B on #A.name_a = #B.name_b

drop table #A
drop table #B
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to combine rows so as to get a result row consisting of the two original rows, then you join. In your case one data set may contain a name the other doesn't, so in your case a `FULL OUTER JOIN` may be appropriate. If it is guaranteed to find each name in both sets or you want to restrict the result to those names occurring in both sets, then `INNER JOIN` instead.

You say that the tables you are showing are query results. This is no problem, as you can join query results just as you join persisted database tables, because, well, a query result is a table, too.

```
select
  name,
  coalesce(q1.cnt, 0) as t1_count,
  coalesce(q2.cnt, 0) as t2_count
from             (select name, count(*) as cnt from t1 group by name) q1
full outer join  (select name, count(*) as cnt from t2 group by name) q2 using (name)
order by name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question, because one table can have name values that the other table does not, you could use `FULL OUTER JOIN`. You could try something like this:

```
SELECT 
  COALESCE(table1.Name, table2.Name) AS Name, 
  COALESCE(table1.Count,0) as "Count table 1",
  COALESCE(table2.Count,0) as "Count table 2"
FROM 
  table1
  FULL OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.Name = table2.Name
;
```